# Assignment of variable in GNU Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new in GNU make. I have a problem understanding Makefile program  inside NETAL software (it can be downloaded from [here](https://bitbucket.org/yuichiro_yasui/netal/overview)).

Inside folder NETAL, there is a file Makefile which includes other files such as make.inc and make.headers.
I understand most of the rules in Makefile inside folder NETAL, except for these:

Line 16 and 22. $(LINK.o) $^ $(LDLIBS) $(OUTPUT_OPTION)

What does $(LINK.o) and $(OUTPUT_OPTION) refer to? I cannot find a definition/assignment of these variable anywhere (neither in make.inc and make.headers).

Line 26 and 30. $(COMPILE.c) $< $(OUTPUT_OPTION)

Same problem with variable $(COMPILE.c). I can't find its assignment anywhere, and what it refers to. Also I don't understand the meaning of $<  (and why "<" has to be preceded by a dollar sign "$"). I know dollar sign is for variable, just like in PHP.

I have knocked myself out reading the manual (RTFM, I know): [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)

And this is the result of my reading: In Chapter 4.3 Types of Prerequisites, I found an example which similar with what I am looking for:

```
    OBJDIR := objdir
    OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)
    $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
       $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
    all: $(OBJS)
       $(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)
    $(OBJDIR):
       mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

Unfortunately, there is no explanation about what is "$(COMPILE.c)", "$(OUTPUT_OPTION)", and "$<" .

Can someone explain it to me in a way that is easier for me to understand?
Or give me a link/keyword so that I can Google further.

Comment: run `make -pn | less` and you can see exactly what those variables are defined to.

Comment: To be explicit about it, GNU make has a large catalog of built-in macros and predefined implicit rules.  These are some of them.  To see them all, you can ask make to print its rule database with the `-p` option.  If you just want to see the built-in macros/rules and not your own, you can use `make -p -f /dev/null` (that assumes you're on a UNIX system like Linux or MacOS).

Comment: user657267 & MadScientist: thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are prefedined make variables. From the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-OUTPUT_005fOPTION):

> Every rule that produces an object file uses the variable OUTPUT_OPTION. make defines this variable either to contain ‘-o $@’, or to be empty, depending on a compile-time option.

and

> make follows the convention that the rule to compile a .x source file uses the variable COMPILE.x. Similarly, the rule to produce an executable from a .x file uses LINK.x; and the rule to preprocess a .x file uses PREPROCESS.x.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. So it is taken from this chapter (GNU make manual): 10.3 Variables Used by Implicit Rules, which I haven't read yet.